# g++ __FUNCTION__ replace time

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction, g++, c-preprocessor

Can anyone tell when g++ replaces the `__FUNCTION__` 'macro' with the string containing the function name? It seems it can replace it not until it has check the syntactical correctness of the source code, i.e. the following will not work

```
#include <whatsneeded>
#define DBG_WHEREAMI __FUNCTION__ __FILE__ __LINE__

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  printf(DBG_WHEREAMI "\n"); //*
}
```

since after preprocessing using

```
g++ -E test.cc
```

the source looks like

```
[...]

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  printf(__FUNCTION__ "test.cc" "6" "\n"); //*
}
```

and now the compiler rightly throws up because the *ed line is incorrect.

Is there any way to force that replacement with a string to an earlier step so that the line is correct?

Is `__FUNCTION__` really replaced with a string after all? Or is it a variable in the compiled code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any way to force that replacement with a string to an earlier step so that the line is correct?

No. `__FUNCTION__` (and its standardized counterpart, `__func__`) are *compiler* constructs. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` on the other hand, are *preprocessor* constructs. There is no way to make `__FUNCTION__` a preprocessor construct because the preprocessor has no knowledge of the C++ language. When a source file is being preprocessed, the preprocessor has absolutely no idea about which *function* it is looking at because it doesn't even have a concept of functions.

On the other hand, the preprocessor *does* know which file it is working on, and it also knows which line of the file it is looking at, so it is able to handle `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

This is why `__func__` is defined as being equivalent to a static local variable (i.e. a *compiler* construct); only the compiler can provide this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `__FUNCTION__` like a preprocessor macro, but it's a variable (please read http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html).

Try `printf("%s", __FUNCTION__)` just for testing and it will print the function name.

Answer (score 2):

`__FUNCTION__` is not standard. Use `__func__`. As the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Function-Names.html#Function-Names) says, it's as if:

```
<ret-type> function_name( <args> )
{
    static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, the preprocessor will turn `"my " "name " "is " "Bob"` into the string literal `"my name is Bob"`; since `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are preprocessor instructions, `"We are on line " __LINE__` will pass "We are on line 27" to the compiler.

`__FUNCTION__` is normally a synonym for `__func__`. `__func__` can be thought of as a pseudo-function that returns the name of the function in which it is called. This can only be done by the compiler and not by the preprocessor. Because `__func__` is not evaluated by the preprocessor, you do not get automatic concatenation. So if you are using `printf` it must be done by `printf("the function name is %s", __func__);`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DBG_WHEREAMI(X) printf("%s %s(%d): %s\n",__func__,__FILE__,__LINE__,X)

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  DBG_WHEREAMI("Starting");
}
```

Note: Since you marked this as C++ you should probably be using the iostreams to make sure it's type safe.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't allow for something like `DBG_WHEREAMI("Error code %d", errorCode)`. It can't be made to work, either (at least not portably) because C++ doesn't (yet) have variadic macros.

Comment: not quite...
i was wondering if i could generate a string containing __func__ at compile time so that is is runtime constant.
that seems to be impossible.

Comment: @bbb: It is `static const`, and there is zero chance of it being generated at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s" __FILE__ __LINE__ "\n", __FUNCTION__);
```

Yeah, I know that's not really the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you create a class, you can build a message from any number of types as you'd like which means you have a similar effect to the << operator or the format in a printf(3C). Something like this:

```
// make sure log remains copyable
class log
{
public:
  log(const char *function, const char *filename, int line)
  {
    f_message << function << ":" << filename << ":" << line << ": ";
  }
  ~log()
  {
    //printf("%s\n", f_message.str().c_str()); -- printf?!
    std::cerr << f_message.str() << std::endl;
  }

  log& operator () (const char *value)
  {
    f_message << value;
  }
  log& operator () (int value)
  {
    f_message << value;
  }
  // repeat with all the types you want to support in the base class
  // (should be all the basic types at least)
private:
  sstream f_message;
};

// start the magic here
log log_error(const char *func, const char *file, int line)
{
  log l(func, file, line);
  return l;
}

// NOTE: No ';' at the end here!
#define LOG_DEBUG  log_error(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

// usage sample:
LOG_DEBUG("found ")(count)(" items");
```

Note that you could declare the << operators instead of the (). In that case the resulting usage would be something like this:

```
LOG_DEBUG << "found " << count << " items";
```

Depends which you prefer to use. I kind of like () because it protects your expressions automatically. i.e. if you want to output "count << 3" then you'd have to write:

```
LOG_DEBUG << "found " << (count << 3) << " items";
```